# Flask JWT Extended missing csrf access token

Tags: python, flask, cookies, jwt, flask-jwt-extended

My flask application uses JWT as means of authentication. Those tokens are stored in cookies and flask-jwt-extended is configured to use them. For regular GET requests authentication works fine and `@jwt_required` decorator is able to read tokens from cookies and authenticate the user. But when making AJAX POST request using `fetch()` the extension is not able to read them and returns `Missing CSRF token` error. Strangely when accessing request object in the POST route all required cookies are present as well as in all other routes when authenticated, which means that `fetch()` sets all required cookies correctly:

```
ImmutableMultiDict([
('csrftoken', 'valid_csrf_token'),
('session','valid_session_cookie'), 
('access_token_cookie', 'valid_access_token'), 
('csrf_access_token', 'valid_csrf_access_token')
])
```

Flask POST route:

```
@main.route("/sendmail", methods=["POST"])
@jwt_required()
async def send_mail():
    data = json.loads(request.data)
    
    mail_template = render_template("mail-view.html", data=data)

    pdf_report = pdfkit.from_string(mail_template, False)

    message = Message(
        subject="Flask-Mailing module",
        recipients=["recepient-mail@domain.com"],
        body="Message body",
        subtype="html",
    )
    message.attach("report.pdf", pdf_report)
    await mail.send_message(message)
    return jsonify({"message": "success"}), 200
```

Fetch request:

```
fetch(window.location.origin + "/sendmail", {
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
    },
    credentials: "same-origin",
    body: JSON.stringify(mail),
})
```

My app config object:

```
class DevConfig:
    SECRET_KEY = os.environ.get("SECRET_KEY")
    JWT_SECRET_KEY = os.environ.get("JWT_SECRET_KEY")
    JWT_COOKIE_SECURE = False
    SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE = False
    JWT_TOKEN_LOCATION = ["cookies"]
    JWT_ACCESS_TOKEN_EXPIRES = datetime.timedelta(hours=1)

    MAIL_SERVER = "smtp.googlemail.com"
    MAIL_PORT = 587
    MAIL_USE_TLS = True
    MAIL_USE_SSL = False
    MAIL_USERNAME = os.environ.get("MAIL_USERNAME")
    MAIL_PASSWORD = os.environ.get("MAIL_PASSWORD")
    MAIL_FROM = os.environ.get("MAIL_USERNAME")
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With flask-jwt-extended default settings the CSRF-Token needs to be send only for state changing request methods (everything except 'GET'). Thats why the 'GET'-method is authorized even without a CSRF-Token. Secondly, the whole idea of a CSRF-Token is to not send it automatically by the web browser, so it is not accepted within a cookie:

> By default, we accomplish this by setting two cookies when someone
> logging in. The first cookie contains the JWT, and encoded in that JWT
> is the double submit token. This cookie is set as http-only, so that
> it cannot be access via javascript (this is what prevents XSS attacks
> from being able to steal the JWT). The second cookie we set contains
> only the same double submit token, but this time in a cookie that is
> readable by javascript. Whenever a request is made, it needs to
> include an X-CSRF-TOKEN header, with the value of the double submit
> token. If the value in this header does not match the value stored in
> the JWT, the request is kicked out as invalid.

https://flask-jwt-extended.readthedocs.io/en/stable/token_locations/

So whenever you sent a request you should add the CSRF-Token to the headers:

```
fetch(window.location.origin + "/sendmail", {
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
      "X-CSRF-TOKEN": getCookie("csrf_access_token"),
    },
    credentials: "same-origin",
    body: JSON.stringify(mail),
})
```